# I cannot Export level 2 script from miniedit on my Ubuntu 20.04, It sends this error message:

Tags: command-line

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "mininet/examples/miniedit.py", line 3163, in xterm
    if StrictVersion(MININET_VERSION) > StrictVersion('2.0'):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/version.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.parse(vstring)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/version.py", line 137, in parse
    raise ValueError("invalid version number '%s'" % vstring)
ValueError: invalid version number '2.3.0.6'
```

Comment: It looks like you are using an unsupported -dev or rc release of mininet. See for example [encounter error 'invalid version number' #1094](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/issues/1094)

Comment: I search but can't find how to change mininet version from 2.3.0.6 to 2.3.1

Comment: So how did you install version 2.3.0.6? According to `apt policy mininet`, the default version for Ubuntu 20.04 is 2.2.2

Comment: I have fixed and exported successfully, thank you for your discussion!
1. Edit version:
    $ cd mininet
    $ git tag  
    $ git checkout -b mininet-2.3.1b1 2.3.1b1  
    $ cd ..    
    $ mininet/util/install.sh -a 
 
2. See mininet version (currently 2.3.1b): 
    $ mn --version 

Next, Run on python2.7 with the command: 
    $ alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7  
 
3. Now check the command: $ python -V it still shows Python 3.8.10 but don't worry
 
4. Run miniedit: 
    $ sudo ~/mininet/examples/miniedit.py